# Mongoose nested (2 level) find

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, casl

I'm trying to use CASL for authorization check of nested items.
It uses mongoose for query data and check access.

My domain is that:

- A "User" could has more "Vehicles"
- A "Document" must have a Vehicle

Schema:

```
vehicle { users: [ {type: objectId, ref: 'user'} ] }
document { vehicle: {type: objectId, ref: 'vehicle' }}
```

To find the vehicle "by user" I do:

```
db.getCollection('vehicle').find(
    { users: {$in: [ ObjectId("5ae1a957d67500018efa2c9d") ]} }
)
```

That works.

In the documents collection, the data has records such as this:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5aeaad1277e8a6009842564d"),
    "vehicle": ObjectId("5aea338b82d8170096b52ce9"),
    "company": "Allianz",
    "price": 500,
    "date_start": ISODate("2018-05-02T22:00:00.000Z"),
    "date_end": ISODate("2019-05-02T22:00:00.000Z"),
    "createdAt": ISODate("2018-05-03T06:32:50.590Z"),
    "updatedAt": ISODate("2018-05-03T06:32:50.590Z"),
    "__v": 0
}
```

To find the document "by user" I do:

```
db.getCollection('document').find(
    { "vehicle.users": {$in: [ ObjectId("5ae1a957d67500018efa2c9d") ]} }
)
```

It doesn't work. Is possibile to do that in one single "find" query?

Comment: Hi Adriano; could you double-check the collection name in your second query? You say you want to query the _documents_, but it says `getCollection('vehicles')` again. It looks like you're accidentally querying the wrong collection.

Comment: Yes, sorry I fixed my post body.
I'm querying documents with 0 results.

Comment: OK, that's clarified that. I've got another question : could you paste in an example of a document record, which should be returned by your query?

Comment: {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5aeaad1277e8a6009842564d"),
    "vehicle" : ObjectId("5aea338b82d8170096b52ce9"),
    "company" : "Allianz",
    "price" : 500,
    "date_start" : ISODate("2018-05-02T22:00:00.000Z"),
    "date_end" : ISODate("2019-05-02T22:00:00.000Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-05-03T06:32:50.590Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-05-03T06:32:50.590Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it in a simple MongoDB [find() query](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/), because the data about vehicle users exists in the vehicle collection, not the documents collection.

However, it is possible with an [aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) using the [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) operator to link the data in two different collections. The aggregation would be something like this:

```js
db.document.aggregate([
  {$lookup: {
    "from": "vehicle",
    "localField": "vehicle",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "vehicleDetails",
  }},
  {$match: {"vehicleDetails.users" : ObjectId("5ae1a957d67500018efa2c9d")}}
])
```

You will probably need to add more stages to reshape the data the way you need it, but the key is to use $lookup to link the data from the two collections, then use [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) to filter the set of results.

Comment: I don't need the data really. I just Only check that exists a document that it is related to the user "via" the vehicle. To understand the use of this query you can check the examples there https://github.com/stalniy/casl/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 1):

In order for this query to work you need to store `users` ids array in `vehicle` document. Neither Mongo nor CASL doesn't manage external references automatically.

**Alternative solutions**:

So, I see few ways:

1. Retrieve ids of all vehicles when you define rules. This works good in case if amount of vehicles not big (<= 1000)

```js
const vehicleIds = await getVehicleIds(user)

can(['read', 'update'], 'document', { vehicle: { $in: vehicleIds } })
```

2. Denormalize your scheme. For example, add additional `user_id` field to vehicle document
3. Think whether you can embed document as subdocument to vechicle, something like this:

```
vehicle {
  documents: [Document],
  users: [ {type: objectId, ref: 'user'} ]
}
```

4. Just don't define rule per documents and enforce them in routes (REST or GraphQL doesn't matter).

```js
app.get('/vehicle/:id/documents', async (req, res) => {
  const vehicle = await Vehicle.findById(req.params.id)

  req.ability.throwUnlessCan('read', vehicle)
  const documents = Document.find({ vehicle: vehicle.id })

  res.send({ documents })
})
```